# Strange issue with Datagridview-Rows not displayed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh

I have a Datagridview connected to a dataset.The problem is that occasionally,when the data is refreshed,it is not displayed in the DGV.The code is:

```
Private Sub DisplayInDGV()
    Dim SQLSet As String
    Dim DASet As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSSet As New DataSet
    SQLSet = "Select * From SetDisplayTable"

    DASet = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLSet, Con)
    DSSet.Clear()
    DASet.Fill(DSSet, "DSSetHere")
    With DGVSetView

        .Refresh()
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False   
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DataSource = DSSet.Tables(0)

        .Update()
       DGVSetView.Columns(i).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(i).ToString

        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(0).ToString
        .Columns(2).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(1).ToString
        .Columns(3).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(2).ToString
        .Columns(4).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(3).ToString
        .Columns(5).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(4).ToString
        .Columns(6).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(5).ToString
        .Columns(7).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(6).ToString
        .Columns(8).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(7).ToString
        .Columns(9).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(8).ToString
        .Columns(10).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(9).ToString
        .Columns(11).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(10).ToString 'Item Unique Code for Hot Edit
        .Columns(14).DataPropertyName = DSSet.Tables(0).Columns(12).ToString
    End With
    'Updating Totals/::
    For ItemRow As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.Rows.Count - 1
        If DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(14).Value = True Then
            DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(12).Value = DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(10).Value
        ElseIf DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(14).Value = False Then
            DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(13).Value = DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(10).Value

        End If
    Next
    'Updating School and general totals in DGV//:
    Dim SchoolTotal, GeneralTotal As Decimal
    For ColumnTotal As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.Rows.Count - 1

        SchoolTotal += DGVSetView.Rows(ColumnTotal).Cells(12).Value
        GeneralTotal += DGVSetView.Rows(ColumnTotal).Cells(13).Value
    Next
    txtSchoolAmtFinal.Text = SchoolTotal
    txtGeneralAmtFinal.Text = GeneralTotal

    DGVSetView.Update()
    'Get gross total of the DGV amount column//:
    If DGVSetView.RowCount <> 0 Then
        Dim GrossAmt As Decimal = 0

        For Index As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.RowCount - 1
            '  GrossAmt += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(Index).Cells(11).Value)
            If Str(DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) = "Null" Or (DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) <= 0 Then
                MsgBox("Item Number " & (DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) & " is either blank or 0", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Item Error")
            Else
                GrossAmt += Convert.ToDecimal(DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value)
            End If
        Next
        txtInsertGrossAmt.Text = GrossAmt ' - Val(DGVSetView.Text)
        Call SetNetAmount()
    End If
    'Generate Serial//:
    Dim X As Integer
    Do While X < DGVSetView.Rows.Count
        DGVSetView.Item(0, X).Value = X + 1
        X = X + 1
    Loop
    'Disbaling editing in all columns except pending//:
    With DGVSetView
        .Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(3).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(4).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(5).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(6).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(7).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(8).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(9).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(10).ReadOnly = True
    End With
    txtTotalItems.Text = DGVSetView.Rows.Count
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DGVSetView.Rows
        r.Cells(1).Value = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

The problem is that occasionally,the DGV will not show any rows and displays a blank frame.At such instances.if I check in     DGV.Rows.count 
the result is 0 despite there being underlying data in the table.
Note that this happens randomly.At other times the DGV refreshed properly and also displays data correctly.
Also note that this DGV resides within a TabControl.
Further,when the DGV fails to display the data,the totals which I have calculated in the above sub procedure return zero value.As such the problem appears to lie somewhere in the rows not being inserted in the DGV.
Thank you.

Khalid.
//Edit;Code Updated:
@jmcilhinney I have updated my code as follows.However,the earlier problem of the DGV going blank occasionally persists.Also the update process has slowed down slightly.It seems I may be making a mistake in the location of placing the Suspend and ResumeBinding statements:

```
Private Sub SetPreview()
    Dim SQLSet As String
    Dim DASet As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSSet As New DataSet
    SQLSet = "Select * From SetDisplayTable"
    Dim DTDGV As New DataTable
    Dim DGVBindingSource As New BindingSource
    DASet = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLSet, Con)

    DASet.Fill(DTDGV)
    DGVBindingSource.DataSource = DTDGV     
    DGVBindingSource.ResumeBinding()

    With DGVSetView
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .DataSource = DGVBindingSource
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(0).ToString
        .Columns(2).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(1).ToString
        .Columns(3).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(2).ToString
        .Columns(4).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(3).ToString
        .Columns(5).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(4).ToString
        .Columns(6).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(5).ToString
        .Columns(7).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(6).ToString
        .Columns(8).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(7).ToString
        .Columns(9).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(8).ToString
        .Columns(10).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(9).ToString
        .Columns(11).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(10).ToString 'Item Unique Code for Hot Edit
        .Columns(14).DataPropertyName = DTDGV.Columns(12).ToString
    End With

    DGVBindingSource.SuspendBinding()

    'Updating Totals/::
    For ItemRow As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.Rows.Count - 1
        If DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(14).Value = True Then
            DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(12).Value = DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(10).Value
        ElseIf DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(14).Value = False Then
            DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(13).Value = DGVSetView.Rows(ItemRow).Cells(10).Value

        End If
    Next

    'Updating School and general totals in DGV//:
    Dim SchoolTotal, GeneralTotal As Decimal
    For ColumnTotal As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.Rows.Count - 1

        SchoolTotal += DGVSetView.Rows(ColumnTotal).Cells(12).Value
        GeneralTotal += DGVSetView.Rows(ColumnTotal).Cells(13).Value
    Next
    txtSchoolAmtFinal.Text = SchoolTotal
    txtGeneralAmtFinal.Text = GeneralTotal

    DGVSetView.Update()
    'Get gross total of the DGV amount column//:
    If DGVSetView.RowCount <> 0 Then
        Dim GrossAmt As Decimal = 0

        For Index As Integer = 0 To DGVSetView.RowCount - 1
            '  GrossAmt += Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(Index).Cells(11).Value)
            If Str(DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) = "Null" Or (DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) <= 0 Then
                MsgBox("Item Number " & (DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value) & " is either blank or 0", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Item Error")
            Else
                GrossAmt += Convert.ToDecimal(DGVSetView.Rows(Index).Cells(10).Value)
            End If
        Next
        txtInsertGrossAmt.Text = GrossAmt ' - Val(DGVSetView.Text)
        Call SetNetAmount()
    End If

    'Disabling editing in all columns except pending//:
    With DGVSetView
        .Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(3).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(4).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(5).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(6).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(7).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(8).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(9).ReadOnly = True
        .Columns(10).ReadOnly = True
    End With
    txtTotalItems.Text = DGVSetView.Rows.Count
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DGVSetView.Rows
        r.Cells(1).Value = True
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you create a new `DataSet` and then `Clear` it?  What exactly are you trying to clear it of?  I would suggest that what you should be doing is creating a single `DataTable` (NOT a `DataSet`) to begin with, populating it and binding it and then leaving it bound.  When you want to refresh, just suspend binding, clear, repopulate and then resume binding.  Notice I said suspend and resume, which doesn't mean unbinding.  The `DataTable` would remain bound the entire time.  The suspension is to prevent the grid refreshing until the `DataTable` has been repopulated.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thnx for the comment.I added the Dataset.Clear in an effort to solve the issue and then never removed it.
Would it be possible to give me small walkthrough(or link) about how to use the bind method and carry out the steps described above?

Comment: It's 2 AM here. If no one else has answered when I'm next at my machine, I'll do just that.